# Ruby 2.7.1 System Interrupts while installing gems on macOS 11.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Recently Upgraded to Ruby 2.7.1 via rvm. Everything was fine though when trying to install certain gems (e.g. digest-crc) I get the following error. It installs fine on my older ruby 2.5.3.

```
Errno::EINTR: Interrupted system call @ dir_chdir - /Users/person/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/digest-crc-0.6.3/ext/digest
/Users/person/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/digest-crc-0.6.3/ext/digest/Rakefile:23:in `chdir'
/Users/person/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/digest-crc-0.6.3/ext/digest/Rakefile:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/person/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<main>'
```

Self Investigation:
I've found that if I add sleeps around the following code it works, what is going on?

```
file "#{crc}/Makefile" => "#{crc}/extconf.rb" do
    Dir.chdir(crc) do
      begin
        ruby '-S', 'extconf.rb'
      rescue
        fail_gracefully "extconf.rb failed"
      end
      sleep(1) # I manually added this line
    end
  end
```